# Adding rows with specific values in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, key

Hi I have a really large data set in Excel (~43,000 rows) where the first two columns indicate the employee ID and name.  The following 17 columns indicate monthly sales from Jan 13 - May 14.  The problem is the data is pretty disorganized and has repeats of the same employee in different rows (i.e. Employee Mary has different rows each with different data).  Is there a quick Excel function that I can use to sum the 17 columns after the employee ID and name if the ID number and name match, essentially grouping and combining the data belonging to one individual employee in one singular row.  I think the sumif function might work but I don't know how to make the criteria general enough that Excel will know to go through the entire spreadsheet and find the two matching indicators in each row.  I appreciate any input/help!

Comment: I tried running a this data through a Python script and it just takes too long given its size so I think I am only left with Excel as my option to analyze

Answer (score 0):

Sort by ID (which I assume is a unique identifier) then apply Subtotal for each change in ID, to each of the seventeen columns.

Comment: The issue is that there are thousands of employee IDs and I don't want to have to sort through each one individually looking for duplicates.  Would it work if I create a pivot table that autosums the subtotals?